# Why do i get modifiedCount:0 in mongoose when trying to update a document in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am simply trying to update a document with mongoose model using nodejs.

But it just doesn't update the document and logs this result:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

why is that?

Here is my code:

```
  User.update(
        { email: email }, {
            $set: {
                emailKey: key,
                verificationToken: verify_token,
           
            },
        }, {upsert: true, new: true}, function (err,res) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(res)
                    console.log("updated!!!!!")
                }
           });
```

Comment: What are the values of the `emailKey` and`verificationToken` in the document in the database (with the given value for `email`) and what are the values of `key` and `verify_token` in the code? Presumably they are the same, hence why the document isn't changed

Comment: @user20042973 emailKey and verificationToken are new values that i want to set, the vaule for email is the email of the user, the value of key is a randomly generated string and so is verify_token it is just a random string

Comment: I would suggest that you go confirm all of that. Look at (all of) the matching documents(s) in the collection and print out the values that the code is using. The database is finding a document with that email value but determining the other fields are the same so it isn't modifying it